# UITableViewController -- event when view changes size?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

The `UITableViewController` changes it's `tableview`'s when the keyboard appears. I'd like the cells to stay where the are; the default behavior is that the view is simply shrunk and the top cell stays where it is.
I'd rather have the bottom cell to stay at the visible button.

There are two approaches I can think of:

- Can I tell the tableview to shrink from the top instead of shrinking from the bottom?
- Can I intercept the change in size? In that case I could call the `scroll` method to scroll to the bottom.

EDIT: I seem not to have been clear. The `UITableView` is actually resized. (Seems to be a feature of the `UITableViewController`. The problem I'm having is the behavior of the `UIScrollView` of the `UITableView` that contains the `UITableViewCell`s. Listening for the `UIKeyboardDidShow` and similar events just to reposition the scroll position feels like shooting sparrows with cannons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Stop using UITableViewController if it doesn't provide the behaviors you want. Instead just create a UIViewController subclass with a UITableView property, listen for the keyboard notifications, and respond however you like; adding insets to the table view and scrolling to keep cells visible as desired.

Comment: You probably could also override the methods `keyboardWasShown:`and `keyboardWillBeHidden:` which are called threw the keyboard notifications.

Comment: Possibly, unfortunately those methods are not part of UITableViewController's public interface so you can't count on overriding them to prevent the controller's default behavior. If UITableViewController declared them in a public interface that would be a fine way to customize its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can control on how the tableview will be resized and/or scrolled the cells in the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. Therefore you first have to make your `UITableViewController`
observing the following two Notifications (not sure if this is necessary for TableViewControllers) :

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

You could do that in your viewDidLoad Method. Then you have to write some code to do what you want. As a starting point I recommend you to use the code snippets out of [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) from the Apple "Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS".